# Creating .gifs corresponding to Quirk simulations

Tags: simulation, quirk

[Craig Gidney's blog](https://algassert.com/2016/05/22/quirk.html) has some .gifs which directly link to the corresponding simulation on [Quirk](https://algassert.com/quirk). For example:

**Grover Search**

[image]

**Delayed Eraser**

[image]

Is it possible to create these .gifs from within Quirk? Or does one need to use some third-party software?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made those GIFs using the screen recorder [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/).

ScreenToGif is not very good at compressing while maintaing quality, so I found it worked better to disable all optimizations while recording, try to preserve all detail, then post-process using [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/)'s ["Optimize (for GIF)" filter](http://blog.gregzaal.com/2015/08/06/making-an-optimized-gif-in-gimp/). GIMP is also handy for e.g. adding the text labels you see in the images.

(There was an old dev version of Quirk that had a "record cycle" button, but it was incredibly slow and didn't produce decent results [you have to find javascript code to encode the GIF data, and you often want to vary the framerate because some things look fine at low rates but some don't] so I dropped it.)

Comment: @Blue It's quite hard to pick a "good" speed for the gifs, and especially for Quirk itself, because people want different amounts of focus at different times. I just eyeball it to where I'm sorta-kinda happy each time.